# my laravel seeds folders ignored by git how to resolve and avoid

Tags: laravel, git, github, module, gitignore

i have `modules` folders in my Laravel Project.

and my sub packages/projects in there

[image: my laravel seeds folders ignored by git how to resolve and avoid]

my Laravel parent project use them to working

[image: similar to vendor how can you create sub projects in laravel]

modules folder gitignored by his main project.

[image: laravel create vendor project]

those projects in modules folders connect to its own git repos.

those projects have `seeds` and `factories` folder need when i run composer install in the parent.

[image: seeds and factories didnt sync with git to repo]

but `seeds` and `factories` are empty and not sync with git and when other developers fetch/clone the repos the parent project need them.

how can i add files as Laravel documentation there to avoide this action.

is it true to create a text file there?

Comment: Just add a file `.gitkeep` in those folders and add to git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git doesn't commit empty folders. Usual solution is to add .gitkeep as empty text file.